# Need for changing floating point precision

Tags: android, renderscript

I have started reading about `RenderScript` in android. I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) particular blog.

While reading I come across the part called **Setting floating point precision**

It might seem as a noob question, but why do we need to change floating point precision? What benefit we get? Anything related to `RenderScript` in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precision is basically what it is. It tells how precise things on screen will be drawn. In some cases floating point precision might be insignificant on its own or in comparison to other thing like memory or performance. If you have a device with small screen and low memory you don't need double precision to draw a model.

Answer (score 2):

These precisions are for the compute part of renderscript. Generally they will not affect rendering in which you will get GL precision which is much lower than IEEE 754 in general, but you shouldn't use that since the graphics part of renderscript is deprecated.

Essentially, you should use rs_fp_relaxed since that will get you onto the highest range of mobile GPU and SIMD-supporting CPU devices.

rs_fp_relaxed enables flush to zero for denorms and round to zero operation. This affects the answer when you do math on half, float and double types. Although you should also avoid double if you want to be accelerated by mobile gpus and also not take a speed hit even on devices which natively support doubles.

I recommend checking out the wiki pages on floats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

The gist is floats are stored in two parts the exponent and the significand similar to scientific notation of 1.23 * 10^13. When the exponent is all 0s, then your number is denormal. So if your calculation results in a value where the exponent is 0, then the significand will also end up being zero instead of the actual value. For float32 the specific values are 1.1754942E-38 (0x7ffff) to 1.4E-45 (0x1) and the corresponding negative values.

Round to zero comes in when you do math with two floating point numbers an implementation will not calculate the extra digit of precision to know which way to round the last bit so you can be off by 1 ulp from a round-to-even implementation. Generally 1 ulp is quite small but the absolute difference depends on where your value lies in the real number space. For example 1.0 is encoded as 0x3f800000. A 1 ulp error could give you 0x3f800001 which is converted to 1.0000001.